# Regex newbie question on start and end of captures

Tags: regex, jmeter

I need some help with regular expressions.  Please see the example below.  I am capturing specific rid values that are contained between between this

```
","children":[
```

and ending with this

```
 
}]}]}
```

as shown below.

My problem is that the block shown below repeats itself several times and I want all rids between the start of `","children":[ to  }]}]}` per block only.

I know I can capture individual rid value with: `rid":"([\w\d\-\."]+)`

But I don't know how to specify to capture all `rid":"([\w\d\-\."]+)` that exist between between the start of `","children":[` to  `}]}]}`

Example:

```
     ","children":[{"type":"stub","context":"","rid":"b1c4922237ce.ee6a3644443fe.10711226e93.d0af7aadbd0-4be3-4353ddd.8b47.f2f4aaf2474f","metaclass":"ASAPModel.BarrierCategory"},
{"type":"stub","context":"","rid":"b1c497ce.ee6a64fe.290c6e93.91c15f91-a1c-4c36.9939.4ab7b94a39ad","metaclass":"ASAPModel.BarrierCategory"},
{"type":"stub","context":"","rid":"b1c497ce.ee6a64fe.27c3ee93.22e90c22-7406-463a.8bff.f6ea88f6ffcc","metaclass":"ASAPModel.BarrierCategory"},
{"type":"stub","context":"","rid":"b1c497ce.ee6a64fe.6a182e93.5c0e7d5c-ff65-451d.afc0.cfc7fbcfc02d","metaclass":"ASAPModel.BarrierCategory"},
{"type":"stub","context":"","rid":"b1c497ce.ee6a64fe.6970ae93.8ea3978e-112b-4bbb.8405.d17071d105d2","metaclass":"ASAPModel.BarrierCategory"}]}]},

     ","children":[{"type":"stub","context":"","rid":"b1c4922237ce.ee6a3644443fe.10711226e93.d0af7aadbd0-4be3-4353ddd.8b47.f2f4aaf2474f","metaclass":"ASAPModel.BarrierCategory"},
{"type":"stub","context":"","rid":"b1c497ce.ee6a64fe.290c6e93.91c15f91-a1c-4c36.9939.4ab7b94a39ad","metaclass":"ASAPModel.BarrierCategory"},
{"type":"stub","context":"","rid":"b1c497ce.ee6a64fe.27c3ee93.22e90c22-7406-463a.8bff.f6ea88f6ffcc","metaclass":"ASAPModel.BarrierCategory"},
{"type":"stub","context":"","rid":"b1c497ce.ee6a64fe.6a182e93.5c0e7d5c-ff65-451d.afc0.cfc7fbcfc02d","metaclass":"ASAPModel.BarrierCategory"},
{"type":"stub","context":"","rid":"b1c497ce.ee6a64fe.6970ae93.8ea3978e-112b-4bbb.8405.d17071d105d2","metaclass":"ASAPModel.BarrierCategory"}]}]},
```

My problem is that I don't understand how to specify the beginning and end values of where to start the non capturing group and how to say identify one or more of these capture groups sort of like `[]+`

Comment: Suggest indenting your data with four spaces so SO can format it for display a bit more usefully.

Comment: thanks for including sample data. Can you also include a sample of what it is exactly you want to capture?

Comment: updated what i want to capture...

Comment: @MaxiePaxie Are you trying to do this in Perl or JavaScript?

Comment: @Sinan sorry I think I was inaacurate in lableling this perl. Jmeter uses Jakarta-ORO Java classes, and 'Per like' matching sytanx.  Sorry for the confusion removing perl tag from question..

Answer (score 6):

This looks like [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) (though you example data is incomplete to be valid).

If so then perhaps [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/dist/JSON/) module from [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org) might be best way forward:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON qw( from_json );

# my example data
my $data = q( [ 
    {"children":[ {"type":"stub","rid":"aa"}, {"type":"stub2","rid":"bb"} ] }, 
    {"children":[ {"type":"stub","rid":"cc"}, {"type":"stub2","rid":"dd"} ] } ]
);

my $json = from_json( $data );

for my $rec ( @$json ) {
    for my $child ( @{ $rec->{children} } ) {
        say "rid: ", $child->{rid};
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
rid: aa
rid: bb
rid: cc
rid: dd
```

Comment: Agreed. There are places where a regexp will just be frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

You need to break this up into two steps:

1. Get the length of data
2. Get the rids

   ```
   # Make sure you get the first one
   my ( $child ) = $record =~ m/"children":\[([^\]]+)\]/g;
   # Get all in span - the g operator tells the regex to get all ( 'global' )
   my @rids     = $child =~ m/"rid":"([^"]+)"/g; # <-- g operator
   ```

But it looks like JSON to me, and you could parse data like this with [JSON::Syck](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON::Syck)

Comment: Its a reposne from dojo tree and I'm using Jmeter which uses perl regular expressions. I need the rids to correlate further requests aka dynamic number of http requests with dyanmic rid values...

Comment: @unknown: So you want to know how you can do this *entirely* with regex? There is definitely not an easy method for that.

Comment: @Axeman I was always told that anythings possible in regex....world peace, space travel, and even complex parsing...

Comment: @MaxiePaxie you were told wrong. @Axeman I am afraid he is trying to do this in Javascript, not Perl.

Answer (score 0):

some thing like `\",\"children\":(.*)(?=\\]\\}\\]\\})`

play around with it

**the forum is absorbing some of my backslashes, word of warning to double up for anyone else**

*in response to edits*

Try breaking up the data into its bracketed groups first, then doing one search for each in a for loop. you can get all the groups at once using regex groups.

Comment: Backslashes will come through fine if you mark the string as code using \`...\`